# Возможно ли динамическое отслеживание размеров блока?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Здравствуйте.
С Vue только начал знакомиться недавно(сам верcтальщик) и у меня такой вопрос?
(наверное даже два)

1) можно ли каким то образом динамически отслеживать размеры блока?
Если я правильно понимаю то methods, computed не позволяют это добиться - возможно как то с помощью watch это можно реализовать?
(например поятоянно мониторить св-во this.$el.clientWidth)

2) есть такой код:
https://jsfiddle.net/Mike_kharkov/uyydduap/29/

```js
const SubWrapper = {
  template: '#sub-wrapper',
  
  data: function () {
    return {
      width: '',
      subData: {propA: '777'}
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    x: function () {
      this.width = this.$el.clientWidth;
    }
  }
};

const MyTemplateCanvas = {
  template: '#my-template-canvas',
  
  props:['name'],
  
  data () {
    return {
      configKonva: {
        width: 600,
        height: 600,
        stroke:'gray'
      },
      configCircle2: {
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        width: 260,
        height: 160,
        fill: "gray",
        stroke: "#2a1725",
        strokeWidth: 2
      }
    }
  }
};

Vue.use('VueKonva');

const root = new Vue({
  el: '.wrapper',
  components: {
    SubWrapper,
    MyTemplateCanvas
  }
});
```

```css
div, span, a, ul, li, dl, dt, dd, fieldset, form, label, button, input, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, strong, p, br, i, figure, figcaption {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0 none;
}

:focus {
    border: 0 none;
}

button, a:hover, label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

img {
    border: medium none;
}

a:active, a:focus, img, input, textarea {
    outline: none;
}

a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    overflow: auto;
}

th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .sub_wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.konvajs-content{
    width: 100% ! important;
}
.wrapper .sub_wrapper canvas{
    background-color: #c0c0c0 ! important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>MK Trading</title>
  <link href="style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <sub-wrapper>
      <my-template-canvas></my-template-canvas>
    </sub-wrapper>
  </div>

  <script id="sub-wrapper" type="text/x-template">
    <div class="sub_wrapper">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </script>

  <script id="my-template-canvas" type="text/x-template">
    <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
      <v-layer ref="layer">
        <v-rect ref="zzz" :config="configCircle2"></v-rect>
      </v-layer>
    </v-stage>
  </script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/konva'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue-konva'></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

вопрос:
каким образом я могу(допустим статически) передать значение ширины родительского блока ребенку - через например props?

Comment: Ничего не понял из вопроса что не получается сделать... 1. Зачем отслеживать изменения блока, как меняется этот блок, с помощью каких событий? 2. Во `vuejs` передача параметров от родителя к дочернему происходит через `props` , а от ребенка к родителю через `$emit` .

Comment: На StackOverflow необходимо в одном вопросе писать один вопрос, так что второй вопрос лучше оформить отдельно.

Comment: понял. Так и сделал.
(создал новую ветку.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам HTML + JavaScript не содержит прямой функциональности для отслеживания размеров элемента, но можно использовать JavaScript библиотеки для этого.

Вот одна для `Vue.js` - https://github.com/Akryum/vue-resize

Пример использования cо страницы плагина:

```
<template>
  <div class="demo">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <resize-observer @notify="handleResize" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleResize () {
      console.log('resized')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Cпасибо! Понял - все заработало.
А на счет получения данных от родителя к ребенку именно в данной конфигурации(структуре) кода - не подскажите рабочий вариант?
Что только не пробовал уже - всегда или андефайнд выдает или ошибку в консоли..

Comment: @MikeKharkov это лучше всего отдельным вопросом оформить. Так же если ответ вам подошёл, отметьте его пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло в аналогичной проблеме. Добавлю, что необязательно нужно добавлять в тот же элемент, это не всегда возможно, когда нужно отловить изменение составной части другого импортированного компонента, но скорее всего можно добавить внешний контейнер, который будет иметь те же размеры, а потом вычесть что-то постоянное (рамки, паддинги и т.д.).